# .htaccess deny/allow specific folder within my current rules

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess

I am using a `.htaccess` rule similar to the below:

```
# BEGIN Disable access to all files EXCEPT
Order deny,allow
Deny from all

# Files
<Files ~ ".(doc|xlsx|xlsm|xls|pdf|docx|txt|rtf|rdf|odf)$">
    Allow from all
</Files>
# Page Content
<Files ~ ".(css|js)$">
    Allow from all
</Files>
# Images
<Files ~ ".(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|cur|ico|webp)$">
    Allow from all
</Files>
# Fonts
<Files ~ ".(svgz?|eot|otf|tt[cf]|woff2?)$">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

However, I also want to allow one specific `.php` file, I don't want to have to put a .htaccess rule in the folder where the specific `.php` file exists so I've been trying to do it with `FilesMatch`

Here are some examples:

```
<FilesMatch "\/folder1\/folder2\/folder3\/folder4\/\.(php)">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any   
</FilesMatch>

<FilesMatch "\folder1\folder2\folder3\folder4\file1.php">
    Allow from all
    Satisfy Any   
</FilesMatch>
```

I've even tried them with `/home/hostaccount/public_html/` at the start of the location and also just `/public_html/` at the start of the location.

I've tried adding `^` to the start of the location and finished it off with `$` at the end.

Anyone know what I am doing wrong and more importantly how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's not much difference between `<Files ~ "...">` or `<FilesMatch "...">` (or `<Files "...">` in this context) since they all just match against the file basename, excluding the directory path.

So, if the files basename is *unique* within this directory tree then you can simply do:

```
<Files "file-to-allow.php">
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

However, this will match `file-to-allow.php` *anywhere* within this directory tree, if the same file basename occurs in multiple directories.

If you needed to match the full filesystem path (or strictly speaking the URL-path), without using a `.htaccess` file in the target subdirectory and without access to the server config (which would allow you to use a `<Directory>` container), then you could perhaps do something like the following, with the help of mod_setenvif:

```
SetEnvIf Request_URI "^/path/to/file-to-allow\.php$" letmein

Allow from env=letmein
```

The `SetEnvIf` directive sets the environment variable `letmein` if the `Request_URI` matches the specific URL (regex). This is then used in the following `Allow` directive to only *allow* if the environment variable is set.